# How to get the average temperature of three order by id descending in SQL?

Tags: mysql

```
 id      timing     temp    temp1   temp2   temp3
 5260     1446746934  -76     -15      4       25
    5259    1446746332  -75     -14      5      25
    5258    1446745731  -77     -15      6      25
    5257    1446734343  -71     -10      0      21
```

I have hundred of data like above. The database will get new values and insert into new row 5261. I tried to select first three rows average in temp column for instance this case is value of -76,-75,-77. So the average value should return -76. I know something wrong in my SQL code.

```
SELECT avg(temp) as temperature from tempArray  order by id DESC limit 3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT avg(t.temp) as temperature 
              from (select temp from tempArray  order by id DESC limit 3) t;
```

(select temp from tempArray  order by id DESC limit 3) t  --- select the first three entries in the table, and named this table - 't'. Then calculate the average

Comment: Thank you very much.. that is what i want.

Comment: can you explain the query for me please?

Answer (score 0):

use `Group by` with `AVG`

```
SELECT avg(temp) as temperature from tempArray where id 
in( SELECT * from (SELECT id temperature from tempArray order by id DESC limit 3) as t)
```

Comment: The result is not what I want.  I only need to average the first three.

Comment: SELECT avg(temp) as temperature from tempArray where id in (SELECT id temperature from tempArray  order by id DESC limit 3)

Comment: try this query @user2573051

Comment: or this...  SELECT temp temperature from tempArray  order by id DESC limit 1,2

Comment: i tried the first query. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'. The second return me -75,-77

Comment: SELECT temp temperature from tempArray order by id DESC limit 1,2

Comment: or this ... SELECT avg(temp) as temperature from tempArray where id in( 
SELECT * from (SELECT id temperature from tempArray  order by id DESC limit 3) as t);